# Webmin Navigation Menu

Tags: webmin

I'm being a complete dullard and cannot for the life of me remember how to add a module to the navigation menu within webmin!

At the minute in the navigation menu under the Servers tab I only have 4 servers listed two of which i don't use.

All I want to do is add another module that is already installed to the list and remove the ones I do not use.

Answer (score 1):

Try Webmin > Webmin Configuration > Reassign Modules

This allows you to choose which module appears in which section of the admin bar. It doesn't actually install or remove anything, just changes how it is shown.

If you want to actually install or delete modules (not normally necessary) then you want Webmin > Webmin Configuration > Webmin Modules